# Two Ajax methods being executed one after the other

Tags: knockout.js

I am facing a very weird issue in my Javascript code.I have an ajax call to update details in the database.I also have another method I am calling when the user wants to cancel the edits.When I click on the Update Button,The cancel edits method is also getting called.

The code is as follows

```
 var provider = function () {
   var self = this;
if ((providerEditInfo.Certification == "M.D.") || (providerEditInfo.Certification == "M.B.B.S")) {
    specialities = ["Dermatology", "Hematology", "Neurology"];
}
else if ((providerEditInfo.Certification == "R.N.") || (providerEditInfo.Certification == "M.S.N.")) {
    specialities = ["Pediatric Nursing", "Critical Care Nursing", "Occupational Health Nursing"];
}
self.providerID = ko.observable(providerEditInfo.ProviderID);
self.firstName = ko.observable(providerEditInfo.FirstName);
self.lastName = ko.observable(providerEditInfo.LastName);
self.certificationArray = ko.observableArray(["M.B.B.S", "M.D.", "R.N.", "M.S.N."]);
self.certification = ko.observable(providerEditInfo.Certification);
self.specializationArray = ko.observableArray(specialities);

self.updateProviderDetails = function (provider) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Provider/UpdateProviderDetails/",
        type: "POST",
        data: provider,
        async:false,
        success: function (result) {
            if (result.url) {
                location.href = result.url;
            }
        }
    });
};

 self.cancelEdits = function () {
    if (confirm('Are you sure you want to Cancel?')) {
        window.location.href = '/Provider/ShowTheListOfProviders';
       }
  };
}; 

$(document).ready(function () {
    ko.applyBindings(new provider());  
 });
```

The HTML is

```
 @model Greenway.Demo.DataAccess.Entity.Provider
<body>
   <div class="container">
      <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" id="editProviderDetailsForm">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label labelfont">First Name:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" autofocus="autofocus" placeholder="Enter the First Name" id="firstName" name="firstName" data-bind="value:firstName , event: { keypress: allowOnlyAlphabets }">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label labelfont">Last Name:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter the Last Name" id="lastName" name="lastName" data-bind="value:lastName ,event: { keypress: allowOnlyAlphabets }">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label labelfont">Specialization:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <select class="form-control" id="specialization" name="specialization" data-bind="value:specialization,options:specializationArray, optionsCaption: 'Select a Specialization'"></select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group text-center">
            <button type="button" data-bind="click: updateProviderDetails" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>
            <button type="button" data-bind="click: cancelEdits" class="btn   btn-primary">Cancel</button>
        </div>
    </form>
   </div>
   </body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
       var providerEditInfo = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));
</script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="../../App_Scripts/Shared/Functions.js">     </script>
```

For ease of understanding,I have also attached,a pic of the issue.
[image]
Any help would be appreciated.I am new to Javascript and Ajax and this issue seems a little out of my league.

Comment: What other libraries besides jQuery are you using? edit: nevermind, I see the edit.

Comment: Knockout.js , Jquery Validations and Bootstrap as well.I have removed the code for jquery validations from document ready,since I thought it might not have been responsible for the issue.

Comment: What happens when you call the `Cancel` button. Is it working as expected ?

Comment: Yes,it is working as expected.Even update is happening,its just that the pop up keeps popping up.In the dialog box,once I click on either Cancel or Ok,I am redirected to another page with the Update showing up.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about this, but give a try and check.

remove below code from the function itself.

```
self.updateProviderDetails = function (provider) {
$.ajax({
    url: "/Provider/UpdateProviderDetails/",
    type: "POST",
    data: provider,
    async:false,
    success: function (result) {
        if (result.url) {
            location.href = result.url;
        }
    }
});
 };

    self.cancelEdits = function () {
       if (confirm('Are you sure you want to Cancel?')) {
            window.location.href = '/Provider/ShowTheListOfProviders';
    }
   };
```

and add the code below the function.

```
  provider.prototype = {

  updateProviderDetails : function (provider) {
          $.ajax({
              url: "/Provider/UpdateProviderDetails/",
              type: "POST",
              data: provider,
              async:false,
              success: function (result) {
                  if (result.url) {
                       location.href = result.url;
                  }
              }
         });
  };

  cancelEdits : function () {
       if (confirm('Are you sure you want to Cancel?')) {
          window.location.href = '/Provider/ShowTheListOfProviders';
       }
  };
 };
```

Comment: Do I need to change the call in the HTML as well?

Comment: I don't think so. Sorry I don't have a clear idea also. Just try without changing the HTML

Comment: Actually,I removed the provider parameter in the Update method and now I dont get the cancel dialog.But the data is not getting updated though.Any thoughts on that Sir

Comment: why did you remove the `provider` parameter ? What happens if you don't remove it ?

Comment: I,now dont get the cancel dialog box when I click on Update.But the data is not getting updated now

Comment: in this `url: "/Provider/UpdateProviderDetails/",` just print the values of the form. If the data are passed to that file (I think its a controller file ) the data will be displayed. if so then the problem is in that method onward.

Comment: The values that is being passed to the controller are all null except for the id which is 0.I checked these values while debugging.

Comment: what about before calling the ajax method ? 
updateProviderDetails : function (provider) {
          `// check the values of provider here`
          $.ajax({
         .....

Comment: I am not sending the provider as a parameter the moment.If i did that I would once again face the issue of the cancel dialog again.